# Not able to decrypt bitlocker encrypted drive

Tags: windows-7, encryption

I have encrypted the internal drive using bitlocker in windows 7. Now when I try to unlock it by entering password, it shows 'I/O device not available' error. I also tried unlocking it using recover key but it shows 'the characters in recovery key are not correct'. I have some important data in it so don't want to format it.
Please suggest how to access the drive.

Comment: You are out of luck.  If the recovery key is being rejected and you cannot mount the drive normally due to an I/O error then you are out of options.

Comment: BitLocker doesn't have any known back doors so there isn't any way to bypass the encryption. If you are sure of your password and it is telling you that your IO device is unavailable, there is a possibility that the drive may be failing. If that were the case a local data recovery center may be able to decrypt your drive with your provided key.

Comment: Isn't it possible to access the drive in Ubuntu or any other non-windows based computers ?

Comment: I/O error usually means the drive / the USB drive adapter has some kind of defect. This is usually equal to "your data is now gone".

A wrong password is indicated by a message actually saying the password is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Even though the original post is 8 years old now, I think the answers given so far do not address the actual problem.

I/O error usually means the drive / the USB drive adapter has some kind of defect. This is usually equal to "your data is now gone"